# Android Beacon Library works well on one Android 4.4 device, but not another

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon, altbeacon

UPDATE: I have tried a more direct approach (see EDIT 3, below) which yields an interesting lack of data from the beacon on the watch.

Details on non-working device.
Smartwatch (Generic) listed as Bluetooth 4.0 capable
MTK6572 chipset
Model number EC720 (there seem to many variants)
Android 4.4.2
Kernel: 3.4.67 chendalin-Z87-HD3 #1 Dec 27th 2014
Build Number: H82D.SMARTWATCH.OC4.0.20141447
Custom build version: 1419655453

I  am testing the same application using the same Radius Networks Tag beacons. In this test I have the same 4 beacons within close range of my devices.

Device 1 is a Nexus 7 (2013) that i have not yet updated to Android L, it is running 4.4.4

Device 2 is a generic smart watch, running android 4.4.2 on a MTK6572. Specs list it as having bluetooth 4.0

When I run my testing application using the Android Beacon Library the Nexus reports beacons but the smartwatch does not. It seems to detect them however, I see entries in logcat such as: D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onScanResult() - Device=E5:E0:20:CF:63:32 RSSI=-60. It seems these messages normally show up when the BeaconParser is not setup to read the correct type of beacons but in my case I am pretty sure this is not the issue because the nexus sees the beacons with the exact same code.

The log output for the looks very different for the 2 devices, I am starting to wonder if the android build for the watch somehow as BLE support disabled or has an incomplete stack. I have double checked that bluetooth is on and also wanted to note that the watch has App Permission Management which i set to "Always Allow" for all permission requested by the Application.

Here parts of logcat when from the smartwatch:

```
02-03 19:40:40.393    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconManager﹕ This consumer is not bound.  binding: com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl.Scan@41c7d2c0
02-03 19:40:40.435    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconManager﹕ consumer count is now:1
...
02-03 19:40:40.617    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/BeaconService﹕ beaconService version 2.1 is starting up
02-03 19:40:40.638    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/CycledLeScanner﹕ This is not Android 5.0.  We are using old scanning APIs
02-03 19:40:40.645    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator﹕ Finding best distance calculator for 4.4.2,KOT49H,EC720,alps
02-03 19:40:40.645    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/AndroidModel﹕ Score is 0 for LGE;Nexus 4;KOT49H;4.4.2 compared to alps;EC720;KOT49H;4.4.2
02-03 19:40:40.645    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/AndroidModel﹕ Score is 0 for LGE;Nexus 5;LPV79;4.4.2 compared to alps;EC720;KOT49H;4.4.2
02-03 19:40:40.645    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator﹕ Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
02-03 19:40:40.645    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator﹕ Finding best distance calculator for 4.4.2,KOT49H,EC720,alps
02-03 19:40:40.645    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/AndroidModel﹕ Score is 0 for LGE;Nexus 4;KOT49H;4.4.2 compared to alps;EC720;KOT49H;4.4.2
02-03 19:40:40.646    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/AndroidModel﹕ Score is 0 for LGE;Nexus 5;LPV79;4.4.2 compared to alps;EC720;KOT49H;4.4.2
02-03 19:40:40.646    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator﹕ Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
02-03 19:40:40.648    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconService﹕ No org.altbeacon.beacon.SimulatedScanData class exists.
02-03 19:40:40.649    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/ActivityThread﹕ SVC-CREATE_SERVICE handled : 0 / CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@41cbbec8 className=org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService packageName=com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl intent=null}
02-03 19:40:40.650    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/BeaconService﹕ binding
02-03 19:40:40.656    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/ActivityThread﹕ SVC-BIND_SERVICE handled : 0 / BindServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@41cbbec8 intent=Intent { cmp=com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl/org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService }}
02-03 19:40:40.723    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/GraphicBuffer﹕ create handle(0x552ed2b8) (w:256, h:240, f:1)
02-03 19:40:40.725    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/MaliEGL﹕ [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
02-03 19:40:40.725    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/MaliEGL﹕ [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
02-03 19:40:40.725    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/GraphicBuffer﹕ close handle(0x552ed2b8) (w:256 h:240 f:1)
02-03 19:40:40.733    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/GraphicBuffer﹕ create handle(0x553ec108) (w:256, h:240, f:1)
02-03 19:40:40.735    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-03 19:40:40.737    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/GraphicBuffer﹕ create handle(0x5542c8a8) (w:768, h:768, f:1)
02-03 19:40:40.741    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl W/MALI﹕ MTK_AUX_isMTKFormat:168: int MTK_AUX_isMTKFormat(ANativeWindowBuffer_t*): format=1
02-03 19:40:40.743    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ setViewport 240x240 <0x553ec690>
02-03 19:40:40.745    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconManager﹕ we have a connection to the service now
02-03 19:40:40.747    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconManager﹕ callback packageName: com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl
02-03 19:40:40.747    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconManager﹕ This consumer is already bound
...
02-03 19:40:40.814    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/BeaconService﹕ start ranging received
02-03 19:40:40.814    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconService﹕ Currently ranging 1 regions.
02-03 19:40:40.814    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/CycledLeScanner﹕ start called
02-03 19:40:40.828    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/CycledLeScanner﹕ starting a new scan cycle
02-03 19:40:40.829    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ isEnabled
02-03 19:40:40.834    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/CycledLeScanner﹕ starting a new bluetooth le scan
02-03 19:40:40.835    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ startLeScan(): null
02-03 19:40:40.874    2620-2633/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=1
02-03 19:40:40.879    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/CycledLeScanner﹕ Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 1100 milliseconds
02-03 19:40:40.880    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/CycledLeScanner﹕ Scan started
02-03 19:40:40.880    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/CycledLeScanner﹕ Set scan periods called with 1100, 0  Background mode must have changed.
02-03 19:40:40.881    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/CycledLeScanner﹕ We are not in the background.  Cancelling wakeup alarm
02-03 19:40:40.881    2620-2620/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/CycledLeScanner﹕ cancel wakeup alarm: null
02-03 19:40:41.084    2620-2634/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onScanResult() - Device=E5:E0:20:CF:63:32 RSSI=-45
02-03 19:40:41.084    2620-2634/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/CycledLeScannerForJellyBeanMr2﹕ got record
```

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
    mHandler = new android.os.Handler();
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.setDebug(true);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(" m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    beaconManager.bind(this);
    sendBeacons();

}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            System.out.println("------- didRangeBeacons!!!!");
            iBeacons = beacons;
            System.out.println("------ num:: " + iBeacons.size());

            /*
            for(Beacon iBeacon : iBeacons) {

                Log.i("Beacon", "found \nProxUUID: " + iBeacon.getId1()
                        + "\ntx: " + Integer.toString(iBeacon.getTxPower())
                        + "\nmanu: " + Integer.toString(iBeacon.getManufacturer())
                        + "\ndistance: " + Double.toString(iBeacon.getDistance())
                        + "\nRSSI:" + Integer.toString(iBeacon.getRssi())
                        + "\nTxPow:" + Integer.toString(iBeacon.getTxPower())
                        + "\nBeacon type code:" + Double.toString(iBeacon.getBeaconTypeCode())
                        + "\n------------------------------------------------");
            }
            */

        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("briansbeacons", null, null, null));
    } catch(RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    beaconManager.bind(this);
}
```

EDIT 1:

Adding more specific log entries to try to show the differences in beacon detection: I removed all but one beacon, I noticed that the working device is identifying the beacon by UUID, the non-working is not. But i can not find any reference to the Device=E5:E0:20:CF:63:32 in the log of the working device.

Nexus 7 (working):

```
02-02 23:48:14.795  10727-10751/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconService﹕ beacon detected multiple times in scan cycle :id1: 2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6 id2: 4 id3: 101
02-02 23:48:14.795  10727-10751/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconService﹕ beacon detected :id1: 2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6 id2: 4 id3: 101
02-02 23:48:14.795  10727-10751/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconService﹕ looking for ranging region matches for this beacon
02-02 23:48:14.795  10727-10751/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconService﹕ matches ranging region: id1: null id2: null id3: null
02-02 23:48:14.795  10727-10751/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/RangeState﹕ adding id1: 2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6 id2: 4 id3: 101 to existing range for: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.RangedBeacon@41eb5380
02-02 23:48:14.915  10727-10738/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/CycledLeScannerForJellyBeanMr2﹕ got record
02-02 23:48:14.915  10727-10759/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconParser﹕ This is not a matching Beacon advertisement.  (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011a0bff4c0009060102c0a801130000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
02-02 23:48:14.915  10727-10759/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconParser﹕ This is not a matching Beacon advertisement.  (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 02011a0bff4c0009060102c0a801130000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

SmartWatch (not working):

```
02-02 23:46:52.598    3351-3364/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onScanResult() - Device=E5:E0:20:CF:63:32 RSSI=-31
02-02 23:46:52.599    3351-3364/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/CycledLeScannerForJellyBeanMr2﹕ got record
02-02 23:46:52.600    3351-3364/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BluetoothDevice﹕ mAddress: E5:E0:20:CF:63:32
02-02 23:46:52.603    3351-3383/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconParser﹕ This is not a matching Beacon advertisement.  (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 0201000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
02-02 23:46:52.603    3351-3383/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconParser﹕ This is not a matching Beacon advertisement.  (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 0201000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
02-02 23:46:52.605    3351-3383/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconParser﹕ This is not a matching Beacon advertisement.  (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 0201000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
02-02 23:46:53.432    3351-3351/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/CycledLeScanner﹕ Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 98 milliseconds
02-02 23:46:53.531    3351-3351/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/CycledLeScanner﹕ Done with scan cycle
02-02 23:46:53.531    3351-3351/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconService﹕ Calling ranging callback
```

Something else I noticed is that in the non-working device the only references to BeaconService are the following:

```
02-02 23:46:52.364    3351-3351/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BeaconService﹕ Calling ranging callback
02-02 23:46:52.364    3351-3351/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/Callback﹕ attempting callback via intent: ComponentInfo{com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
```

Whereas in the working device most of the logging for the beacon seems to come from that class...

EDIT - Update 2:

In response to David in regards to the MAC address

The following code:

```
beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
    System.out.println("------- didRangeBeacons!!!!");
    iBeacons = beacons;
    System.out.println("------ num:: " + iBeacons.size());


    for(Beacon iBeacon : iBeacons) {
        Log.i("Beacon", "\n------------------------------------------------");
        Log.d(TAG, "Mac address is: "+iBeacon.getBluetoothAddress());
        Log.i("Beacon", "\n------------------------------------------------");
    }


    }
});
```

Produces on the working Nexus 7:

```
02-03 19:44:57.200    3192-3438/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/System.out﹕ ------- didRangeBeacons!!!!
02-03 19:44:57.200    3192-3438/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/System.out﹕ ------ num:: 1
02-03 19:44:57.200    3192-3438/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/Beacon﹕ ------------------------------------------------
02-03 19:44:57.200    3192-3438/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/RangingActivity﹕ Mac address is: E5:E0:20:CF:63:32
02-03 19:44:57.200    3192-3438/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/Beacon﹕ ------------------------------------------------
```

And on the smartwatch:

```
02-03 19:40:46.671    2620-2671/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/System.out﹕ ------- didRangeBeacons!!!!
02-03 19:40:46.671    2620-2671/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/System.out﹕ ------ num:: 0
```

So there are no ble devices being "seen" by the BeaconManager (or underlying android APIs) as beacons, but yet it does identify the beacon with same MAC address with this line:

```
02-03 19:40:46.486    2620-2633/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BluetoothDevice﹕ mAddress: E5:E0:20:CF:63:32
```

EDIT 3:

I decided to step back and try using the android Bluetooth APIs to query the beacons directly.

Basically I am just trying to output the bytes returned and see why the beacon is not being recognized. And the output looks completely different for the same beacon, only the 1st two bytes have data for the beacon as seen by the smartwatch, while the nexus 7 has 30 bytes of data.

I tried changing the SCAN_TIME with no effect so far.  Is the lack of data received by the watch a sign that it cannot read ble packets?

I used the following code:

```
    private static final long SCAN_TIME = 5000;
    boolean mScanning = false;
    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        Log.i(null, "Inside scanLeDevice");
        Log.i(null, "scan time is: " + SCAN_TIME);
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    Log.i(null, "Calling stopLeScan");
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                }
            }, SCAN_TIME);

            mScanning = true;
            Log.i(null, "Calling startLeScan");
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                                 final byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.i(null, "INSIDE ONLESCAN");
                        //DO MY WORK
                        Log.i(null, "scanned record: " + scanRecord.length);

                        int startByte = 2;
                        boolean patternFound = false;

                        for(int i=0; i<scanRecord.length; i++) {
                            Log.i(null, "byte " + i + ": " + scanRecord[i]);
                        }

                        while (startByte <= 5) {
                            Log.i(null, "scanned record: " + scanRecord.length);

                            Log.i(null, "Identifier check: " + ((int) scanRecord[startByte + 2] & 0xff) + " == " + 0x02);
                            Log.i(null, "Length of data : " + ((int) scanRecord[startByte + 3] & 0xff) + "==" + (0x15));
                            //Log.i(null, " iBeacon Identifier: " + (scanRecord[startByte + 2] & 0xff));
                            if (((int) scanRecord[startByte + 2] & 0xff) == 0x02 && //Identifies an iBeacon
                                    ((int) scanRecord[startByte + 3] & 0xff) == 0x15) { //Identifies correct data length
                                patternFound = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            startByte++;
                        }

                        if (patternFound) {
                            //Convert to hex String
                            byte[] uuidBytes = new byte[16];
                            System.arraycopy(scanRecord, startByte+4, uuidBytes, 0, 16);
                            String hexString = bytesToHex(uuidBytes);

                            //Here is your UUID
                            String uuid =  hexString.substring(0,8) + "-" +
                                    hexString.substring(8,12) + "-" +
                                    hexString.substring(12,16) + "-" +
                                    hexString.substring(16,20) + "-" +
                                    hexString.substring(20,32);

                            //Here is your Major value
                            int major = (scanRecord[startByte+20] & 0xff) * 0x100 + (scanRecord[startByte+21] & 0xff);

                            //Here is your Minor value
                            int minor = (scanRecord[startByte+22] & 0xff) * 0x100 + (scanRecord[startByte+23] & 0xff);

                            System.out.println("-------------output------ : " + uuid + " maj: " + major + " min: " + minor );
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

Here is the output:

nexus 7 (working):

```
02-03 22:50:43.811    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ INSIDE ONLESCAN
02-03 22:50:43.811    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ scanned record: 62
02-03 22:50:43.811    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 0: 2
02-03 22:50:43.811    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 1: 1
02-03 22:50:43.811    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 2: 6
02-03 22:50:43.811    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 3: 26
02-03 22:50:43.811    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 4: -1
02-03 22:50:43.811    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 5: 76
02-03 22:50:43.811    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 6: 0
02-03 22:50:43.821    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 7: 2
02-03 22:50:43.821    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 8: 21
02-03 22:50:43.831    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 9: 47
02-03 22:50:43.831    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 10: 35
02-03 22:50:43.831    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 11: 68
02-03 22:50:43.831    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 12: 84
02-03 22:50:43.831    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 13: -49
02-03 22:50:43.831    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 14: 109
02-03 22:50:43.831    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 15: 74
02-03 22:50:43.831    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 16: 15
02-03 22:50:43.841    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 17: -83
02-03 22:50:43.841    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 18: -14
02-03 22:50:43.841    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 19: -12
02-03 22:50:43.841    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 20: -111
02-03 22:50:43.841    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 21: 27
02-03 22:50:43.841    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 22: -87
02-03 22:50:43.841    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 23: -1
02-03 22:50:43.851    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 24: -90
02-03 22:50:43.851    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 25: 0
02-03 22:50:43.851    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 26: 4
02-03 22:50:43.851    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 27: 0
02-03 22:50:43.851    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 28: 101
02-03 22:50:43.851    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 29: -76
02-03 22:50:43.851    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 30: 0
... (all 0's)
02-03 22:50:43.882    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 61: 0
02-03 22:50:43.882    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ scanned record: 62
02-03 22:50:43.882    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Identifier check: 255 == 2
02-03 22:50:43.882    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Length of data : 76==21
02-03 22:50:43.882    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ scanned record: 62
02-03 22:50:43.882    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Identifier check: 76 == 2
02-03 22:50:43.882    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Length of data : 0==21
02-03 22:50:43.882    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ scanned record: 62
02-03 22:50:43.882    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Identifier check: 0 == 2
02-03 22:50:43.882    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Length of data : 2==21
02-03 22:50:43.882    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ scanned record: 62
02-03 22:50:43.882    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Identifier check: 2 == 2
02-03 22:50:43.882    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Length of data : 21==21
02-03 22:50:43.882    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/System.out﹕ -------------output------ : 2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 maj: 4 min: 101
02-03 22:50:43.912    7303-7303/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Calling stopLeScan
```

smartwatch (not working) :

```
2-03 22:53:37.374    6177-6189/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onScanResult() - Device=E5:E0:20:CF:63:32 RSSI=-46
02-03 22:53:37.376    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ INSIDE ONLESCAN
02-03 22:53:37.376    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ scanned record: 62
02-03 22:53:37.376    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 0: 2
02-03 22:53:37.376    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 1: 1
02-03 22:53:37.376    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 2: 0
02-03 22:53:37.376    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 3: 0
02-03 22:53:37.376    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 4: 0
02-03 22:53:37.376    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 5: 0
02-03 22:53:37.376    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 6: 0
... (all 0's)
02-03 22:53:37.378    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ byte 61: 0
02-03 22:53:37.378    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ scanned record: 62
02-03 22:53:37.378    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Identifier check: 0 == 2
02-03 22:53:37.378    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Length of data : 0==21
02-03 22:53:37.378    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ scanned record: 62
02-03 22:53:37.378    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Identifier check: 0 == 2
02-03 22:53:37.378    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Length of data : 0==21
02-03 22:53:37.378    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ scanned record: 62
02-03 22:53:37.378    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Identifier check: 0 == 2
02-03 22:53:37.378    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Length of data : 0==21
02-03 22:53:37.378    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ scanned record: 62
02-03 22:53:37.378    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Identifier check: 0 == 2
02-03 22:53:37.378    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Length of data : 0==21
02-03 22:53:37.643    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Calling stopLeScan
02-03 22:53:37.643    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
02-03 22:53:37.743    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl I/﹕ Calling stopLeScan
02-03 22:53:37.743    6177-6177/com.mapcushion.android.mapcushionpingl D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
```

Comment: Can you try to get log excerpts from both devices when they detect the same bluetooth mac address?   Try to get a line like `D/BluetoothDevice﹕ mAddress: F8:88:89:A1:E1:30` on the phone followed by a successful detection, and then find the lines following the equivalent detection on the watch.  In both cases, it is important for the mAddress address to match.

Comment: I have added a more concise comparison of the log of the working and non-working device when they detect the beacon.  I cannot find any reference at all to the "D/BluetoothDevice﹕ mAddress: XX:..." in the logs of the working device.  I removed all but one beacon to verify that the devices are both seeing the same one.     Thank you for looking at this!

Comment: Is there a way to force the logging of the mAddress on the working device?  Both have debug set to true.

Comment: You need to get the Mac address of the beacon on the working device.  Try logging in your ranging callback: `Log.d(TAG, "Mac address is: "+beacon.getBluetoothAddress());`

Comment: I added the MAC logging to my callback and detailed it by editing the post.  The watch sees the bluetooth device but it is not being identified and returned by the library as a beacon so the beacons collection is empty.  Also I tried an app from the play store called BLE tool.  On the nexus 7 the beacon is detected as "E5:E0:20:CF:63:32 null" on the watch the beacon is also detected as "E5:E0:20:CF:63:32 null" (not sure what the null is).

Comment: Sorry for the constant editing, I have made some progress that I think will make sense to the right person and is strengthening my feeling that the watch simply cannot read ble packets correctly, though I am not sure why.  See edit 3 for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you confirmed with the Nexus 7 that the beacon has a Mac address of E5:E0:20:CF:63:32, and you see that the watch reads its advertisement as:

```
0201000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

While the Nexus 7 reads it as a very different byte sequence of:

```
02011a0bff4c0009060102c0a801130000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I have to conclude that the watch does not read BLE manufacturer advertisements properly -- it truncates them after two bytes.

The issue may be the MTK6572 ROM, the hardware, or the way the two work together.  It is probably worth documenting the full watch configuration for the sake of others.

Comment: Thank you for all your help!  I have added details to the original post.  We are going to try getting in contact with the manufacturer and I am also going to dig in and see if there are any ROM options for the watch.

Comment: Ever solve this? I have a 2013 Lenovo Yoga 10" Tablet (Android) that has a MediaTek MT8125 (or MT8389) 1.2GHz Quad-Core CPU that has the exact same problem. I suspect it is a problem with the MediaTek BLE implementation. :( I have the kernel source code for an older OS at https://github.com/TeamYogaBlade/lenovo_b6000-8000_kernel_source, which I made a note builds against the MT6589 code.

Comment: I have no solution for this, but I have noticed that if a BLE advertisement has incorrect PDU frame lengths in the header, the bytes will sometimes not be populated properly in the scan.  I have no evidence this is the cause of the problem in this case -- I am just throwing it out there as a possibility.